# Two EditText widgets with TextWatchers cause infinite loop

Tags: android, android-edittext, infinite-loop, textwatcher

I have an interesting issue. I am building a contacts application in android. I have one `EditText` field for Display Name (conjunction of all the name fields) and one `EditText` for each of the name parts (name, surname, nickname). What am I trying to achieve is that on any change in Display Name `EditText` - the appropriate `EditText` content will change and vice versa - at any change in any `EditText` of name part - a Display Name content will change immediately. For this purpose I am using a `TextWatcher` in each `EditText` and one in Display Name:

```
displayName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            parseNameFieldInput(result);
        }
    });
nameData.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                recalculateDisplayName();
            }
        });
```

That caused an **infinite loop** because `parseNameFieldInput` triggered the afterTextChanged of name `EditText` and it triggered the afterTextChanged of the Display Name in its turn. I've decided to add a boolean lock to the method to achieve the needed behaviour:

```
 @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(lock) return;
                lock = true;
                parseNameFieldInput(result);
                lock = false;
            }
        }); 

@Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if(lock) return;
                    lock = true;
                    recalculateDisplayName();
                    lock = false;
                }
```

Now the flow seems to work as expected, but I am still in doubts if I did it correct. The question is what is the best practice to implement several `EditText` fields with `TextWatchers` that may cause an infinite loop. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use

```
removeTextWatcher(nameDataTextWatcher);
```

from the first edittext whenever you are modifying content of second edit text, remove their text watchers. and once the modification is done, you have to again add the same text watcher

Comment: you mean removeTextChangedListener() ?

Comment: I am not sure of removeTextChangedListener() method. but removeTextWatcher(nameDataTextWatcher), i have used many times

Comment: There is no such function in EditText

Comment: Ohh am sorry its removeTextChangedListener() only

Comment: this solution resolves the infinite loop bug, but creates another one: after each entered character the cursor jumps to zero position

Comment: to solve that problem, instead of using settext(), you should use append() method. 
editText.setText("");    
editText.append("Your text");